# How to move array elements to top if compared with string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array $result getting from mysql as follows

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [p_title] => Apple The New iPad (White, 64GB, WiFi)
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [p_title] => Apple ipad Mini/ipad Mini Retina Belkin Fastfit Bluetooth Wireless Key
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [p_title] => Apple ipad Air (16GB, WiFi + Cellular)
        )
)
```

and suppose I am getting sort by value in `$sort_by` variable.
for ex. currently,

> `$sort_by="Apple ipad";`

so I want to move each array elements who have p_title "Apple ipad" to top.

so my output array should be;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [p_title] => Apple ipad Air (16GB, WiFi + Cellular)
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [p_title] => Apple ipad Mini/ipad Mini Retina Belkin Fastfit Bluetooth Wireless Key
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [p_title] => Apple The New iPad (White, 64GB, WiFi)
        )
)
```

I am ready to edit the code either in mysql query or in php.

Comment: so you are reading the array value serially right and does value have  comes in staring of the array value or will it be anywhere in array value

Comment: Have you even tried something?

Comment: @zan yes I am getting value before formig the array, I mean before executing select query. @ Rizier123 Yes as ZI can not use array_multisort() because it needs sorting array. and I knew usort() will do that but I just need to pass a good function in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `usort()`:

```
 function sortx($a, $b) {
    if(strpos($a['p_title'],'Apple ipad')!==false){
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}

usort($array, 'sortx');
```

Whenever the preceding value will contain this string, it will be pushed towards the beginning of the array.

If you want to use variable in `usort()` function, you need to use objects:

```
class SortTitles{
    public $string;
    function sortx($a, $b) {
        if(strpos($a['p_title'],$this->string)!==false){
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    public function sort_titles($array){
        usort($array, 'self::sortx');
        return $array;
    }

}
$sort = new SortTitles;
$sort->string = 'Apple ipad';
$array = $sort->sort_titles($array);
```

Comment: You should also take `$b` into account, `$a` can't be "bigger" or "smaller" just by itself.

Comment: I think `$a` is enough since even though last value had this string, it was pushed to the front anyway. Only now I edited it a bit, with `!==false`

Comment: Thanx n-dru, you gave me answer twice I think.

Comment: check it again if you are returning -1 in first case, it must work. If you use `!` notation, it will also catch case when it is `0`, which coincidentally is true - those strings are in the beginning, so it is `0`!

Comment: No. something is wrong, I did this `if(strpos($a['p_title'],'Apple ipad')){
                            return 1;
                        }
                        return -1;` & working fine.

Comment: only because 'Apple ipad' has index 0, therefore it evaluates to false. Use my way from the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76025/discussion-between-mujahed-akas-and-n-dru).

Comment: Sorry ,my mistake, I forgot `return 1;` after condition.

Comment: Some one please explain me why we are using `!==false` can't we use `===true` or simply `if(condition)`

Comment: @MujahedAKAS read about strpos in manual - it returns the position of the string in another string or false if not exisits, so if searched substring is at the beginning, it returns 0, if it is on second position, then 1 etc. So if you use if(strpos) and it is first, it becomes if(0), which will evaluate to false, like this substring does not exists. That's why you need to compare to false like !==. You cannot also use !=, because then 0==false.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortByTitle($title, $array)
{
  $result = $array;
  for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
  {
    if(isset$array[$i][p_title]) and strpos($array[$i][p_title],$title)!==false)
    {
      unset($result[$i]);
      array_unshift($result,$array[$i]);
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

> The array_unshift() function inserts new elements to an array. The new
>   array values will be inserted in the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This code returns correct result:

```
    $result = array(
        array('p_title' => 'Apple The New iPad (White, 64GB, WiFi)'),
        array('p_title' => 'Apple ipad Mini/ipad Mini Retina Belkin Fastfit Bluetooth Wireless Key'),
        array('p_title' => 'Apple ipad Air (16GB, WiFi + Cellular)'),
    );
    $patterned = array();
    $another = array();
    $sort_by='Apple ipad';
    foreach ($result as $data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($value, $sort_by) === 0) {
                $patterned[][$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $another[][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    sort($patterned);
    $sorted_restult = array_merge($patterned, $another);
```